# Custom System Menu not calling Controller

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, admin-panel

I am using Magento 1.9. In the admin panel, I have created a sub menu named `Whatsapp Notification` inside the `System` menu.

The sub menu in turns have two children menu, named `Template` and `Configuration`.

I created a new module `WhatsappNotification`, and did all the initial setup for the module.

In the `etc/adminhtml.xml` my configuration is as follows :

```
<adminhtml>
<menu>
  <system>
      <children>
          <whatsappnotification translate="title" module="whatsappnotification">
                <title>Whatsapp Notification</title>
                <children>
                    <template>
                        <title>Template</title>
                        <action>whatsappnotification/adminhtml_whatsapptemplate_index</action>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    </template>
                    <config>
                        <title>Configuration</title>
                        <action>whatsappnotification/adminhtml_whatsappconfiguration_index</action>
                        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    </config>
                </children>
            </whatsappnotification>
        </children>
    </system>
</menu> 
</adminhtml>
```

Here I am calling the index method defined in the controller of the respective children menu.

But when I am clicking on either children menu `Template` or `Configuration`, it doesn't redirects to the controller (In the controller I am loading a form, but the call doesn't come to the controller itself).

I am also showing my  `etc/config.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>

<modules>
    <Dbaux_WhatsappNotification>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Dbaux_WhatsappNotification>
</modules>

<global>
    <helpers>
        <whatsappnotification>
            <class>Dbaux_WhatsappNotification_Helper</class>
        </whatsappnotification>
    </helpers> 
    <blocks>
        <whatsappnotification>
            <class>Dbuax_WhatsappNotification_Block</class>
        </whatsappnotification>
    </blocks>
</global>

 </config>
```

And my module structure is as shown :

[image]

Is there anything else that I need to do apart from this to get the call to the controller function?

Comment: Does the provided answer resolves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Admin Router information in your **config.xml**

```
<admin>
  <routers>
    <adminhtml>
        <args>
            <modules>
              <Dbaux_WhatsappNotification before="Mage_Adminhtml">Dbaux_WhatsappNotification_Adminhtml</Dbaux_WhatsappNotification>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </adminhtml>
  </routers>
</admin>
```

Also modify the **adminhtml.xml** as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<adminhtml>
<menu>
  <system>
     <children>
        <whatsappnotification translate="title" module="whatsappnotification">
            <title>Whatsapp Notification</title>
            <children>
                <template>
                    <title>Template</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/whatsapptemplate</action>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                </template>
                <config>
                    <title>Configuration</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/whatsappconfiguration</action>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                </config>
            </children>
        </whatsappnotification>
     </children>
   </system>
  </menu> 
</adminhtml>
```